# What does e2fsck do during bootup?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, fsck, terminology, e2fsck

Please assume I'm using a recent version of Debian Linux, on ext4, on a 2 TB Seagate Momentus hard drive, with all the default settings.

A)  What does e2fsck do during a normal bootup? (And what is this operation called?)

B)  What does e2fsck do after an unclean shutdown? [Edit: According to a [post by Ted Ts'o](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/3/20/247), it does a "journal replay". This normally only takes a few seconds.]

C)  What does e2fsck do once every 30 mounts or so? [Edit: According to Mr. Ts'o, it does a "filesystem consistency check". This normally takes at least a few minutes.]

Answer (score 0):

A>  Ordinarily, `e2fsck` will simply check a partition to determine whether it believes itself to be cleanly unmounted.  If it was, move on to case C.

B>  If the partition seems to have been dirtily unmounted or otherwise claims to need repair, it will then perform a full check of the filesystem (depending on your particular system's startup options).  This "checking and fixing" is called a "filesystem check" (which is what fsck is short for).

C>  Just to be safe, a partition will automatically flag itself as dirty so that upon next inspection, a full check will be run just in case the filesystem's built-in sanity checking has failed or missed some bit rot or other filesystem corruption.  This interval can be adjusted with `tune2fs` (or similar tools for filesystems not in the ext2fs family) utility.  This is also simply called a "filesystem check".

Comment: I thought case B takes just a few seconds, but case C takes five or ten minutes. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends.  Generally, case "C" is the partition just saying "hey, pretend this is case 'B', boss."

Comment: I still believe that case B is much quicker than case C. I've found a source to support my claim, and have edited a link to it into my question. I would downvote you, but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: This answer basically only addresses ext2, not ext3 or ext4, since it doesn't mention the journal (which exists precisely to provide a faster alternative to case B). When there's a journal, an unclean shutdown usually leads to journal replay instead of a full scan.